# odoo 10 - @api.onchange

Tags: python, odoo-10

I am having difficulty in getting the @api.onchange to work.

here are my files

**init**.py

```
from . import models
```

**manifest**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "Sales Test",
    'description': 'test description',
    'depends': ['sale'],
    'category': 'Test',
    'data': [
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': False,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

**init**.py (file under models directory)

```
from . import partner
```

partner.py (file under models directory)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api

class MyPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.onchange('country_id')
    def _onchange_country_id(self):
        self.name = 'OnChange'


    @api.onchange('street', 'zip')
    def _onchange_street(self):
        self.street = 'Test Street'
        return {
            'warning': {
                'title': "Some changes happened",
                'message': "onchange working, bravo!!!",
            }
        },
```

the module is getting installed without any problem and the view is also been altered according to the templates.XML, but nothing happens when change happens to the fields (street, country_id or zip)

Comment: How about a warning

Comment: you already try with @api.constrains('street') ?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of return statement, you have written `,` that's mistake. Other then your code seems to me good. Just make sure it installed perfectly.

I shared my style of onchange() method code.

```py
@api.onchange('street', 'zip')
def _onchange_street(self):
    self.street = 'Test Street'
    warning = {}
    result = {}
    warning = {
        'title': _('Some changes happened!'),
        'message': _('onchange working, bravo!!!'),
    }
    if warning:
        result['warning'] = warning
    return result
```

NOTE:

These requires to import `_` For example.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to make a simple custom logging, it doesnt work too...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class MyPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

@api.onchange('street', 'zip')
def _onchange_street(self):
    save_path = 'C:/temp/odoo.txt'
    file1 = open(save_path, "w")
    toFile = raw_input("street field changed!")
    file1.write(toFile)
    file1.close()       
    self.street = 'Test Street'
    warning = {}
    result = {}
    warning = {
        'title': _('Some changes happened!'),
        'message': _('onchange working, bravo!!!'),
    }
    if warning:
        result['warning'] = warning
    return result
```

tried restarting services also.. no help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this by first importing model and api:

from openerp import api, fields, models, _

Also for odoo 10 you have to be call your onchange function in the field where you try to apply onchange for eg.

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
   def _onchange_product_pack_name(self):
   res = self.product_id.product_pack
   if res:
      return {'domain': {'pack_id': [('id', 'in', [v.id for v in res])]}}

test = fields.Many2one('product.product',string="Pack Products",change_default=True, default=_onchange_action_product_add )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@api.onchange('country_id')
@api.depends('country_id')
def _onchange_country_id(self):
    print'Am here!!'
    self.name = 'OnChange'
```